# radio click on text in an easier way

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, haml

[image]

I use an theme, which can provide my an beautiful UI

The code is sort of dirty, because I need to specify each input an unique id,

Is there any alternative way ?

I wrote it in Haml

```
%input.ace{id: "radio_field_1", name: "radio_field[]", type: "radio", value: "1"}/
%label.lbl{for: "radio_field_1"} 
  radio option 1

%input.ace{id: "radio_field_2",name: "radio_field[]", type: "radio", value: "2"}/
%label.lbl{for: "radio_field_2"} radio option 2

%input.ace{id: "radio_field_3",name: "radio_field[]", type: "radio", value: "3"}/
%label.lbl{for: "radio_field_3"} radio option 3
```

The HTML output

```
<input class="ace" id="radio_field_1" name="radio_field[]" type="radio" value="1">
<label class="lbl" for="radio_field_1">
      radio option 1
    </label>
```

Comment: Not familiar with HAML, but you could wrap the `input` by the `label` element.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a rails [form helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag), not pure HTML, to create your form:

```
- form_tag "/some_path" do
  - 3..times do |i| 
      = radio_button_tag 'radio_field', i, id: "radio_field_#{i}"
      = label_tag 'radio_field, 'radio button #{i}'
```

This should work - will help further if it doesn't

Comment: But what if my radio text `radio option X` are dirrent ?

Comment: You can change them no problem! I'm only going off what you posted in your question -- if you update with actual details, I'll be able to update my answer :)